# Read first column of a space delimited file with Java 8 stream

Tags: java, parsing, io, stream

Code:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 16/11/14.
 */
public class TestStream {
    private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+)\\s+");
    public static String firstWord(String s) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if(matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> x =  Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/testfile"), Charset.defaultCharset()).map(line -> firstWord(line)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will fail with a single-column input like:

```
one
two
three
four
```

Additionally, it will produce odd results with space-prefixed lines like:

```
normal line
   spaceprefixed line
```

The reason it will fail is because the `Files.lines` method trims the line terminators off of each line, so, the input to the regex will be just `one`, etc. Since there's no whitespace after the `one`, the match will fail, and the method will return null.

You should consider an alternative approach of doing [a limited split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split-java.lang.CharSequence-int-), and returning the first value:

```
private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+");

public static String firstWord(String s) {
    return pattern.split(s, 2)[0];
}
```

This also changes the logic slightly because empty lines will return empty-string, instead of null.

Additionally, your code will match `"     spaceprefixed"` from `"     spaceprefixed line"` whereas my code will consider the leading space to be a separator (and not part of the first word), and will match the empty string `""` from `"     spaceprefixed line"`

In other words, I disagree with some of the handling you have with edge cases.

I would handle the edge cases in a different way in the stream too:

```
List<String> x = Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/testfile"), Charset.defaultCharset())
            .map(line -> firstWord(line))
            .filter(word -> !word.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```